# Run SQL-script on databasedump?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a weekly MySQL dump from my production environment intended for our developers. We have a SQL-script which deletes unnecessary production data and anonymouses user information.

Is there any way to run this script, which contains INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE TABLE, without loading the entire database into a secondary MySQL database and without running it on the production database which I obviously do not want?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you wish to accomplish, but it sounds like you want to mangle the data without loading it into some DBMS. You could dump your tables to .sql incl. statements and use bash/perl or similar stuff to mash through it?

Comment: is it a size issue, like before is it 40 units, wanna give 7 units, so you dont wanna take 40 over just to clobber 33 of it ?

Comment: @AndyThompson I might do that, but the database is 2GB compressed.

Comment: @DrewPierce No, it's a privacy issue.

Comment: You might be amazed at how fast simple mangling will be in perl using tools as awk/sed or similar, even on your "massive data". You could even run it dumping only newer records than N (eg. max(id)) and hence have a much smaller set to mangle. I've done it that way before

Comment: @AndyThompson Okay thanks, I will give shell-tools a try. It will run as a cronjob during the night so it does not matter if it takes 1 minute or 30 minutes.